# Could iterating through every DOM element 40 times a second cause performance issues on slower computers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("*").each(function(obj){
        if ($(this).data("x"))
            $(this).css({left:$(this).data("x")()});
        //... more code for y, w, h, x2, y2, etc...
    }
},25);
```

It runs perfectly on my computer - my worry is: if left this way without optimizations, could this code cause significant performance drops for users with worse computers, as it's iterating through every DOM element 40 times a second? Or is that acceptable?

Note: The point is to make it easier to create a function that will coordinate an object's position, for example: `$(myObj).data("x",function(){ return sin(Date.now()/1000)*50; })` should make an object wiggle.

Comment: It could cause performance issues on faster computers, depending on the number of DOM elements. The code should be written in a way such that it's only necessary to iterate through every DOM element at most once, when the code first runs.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you're not concerned with performance.

Comment: For sure, it will kill the battery of any battery-operated device.

Answer (score 2):

It could definitely impact on performance, and especially if you have many, many elements.  40 times a second too?  That seems like a lot.  I'm not sure how much faster using a selector would be either because that too could be expensive.

Perhaps try `$("[data-x]")` as your selector instead, or use a more specific parent selector:  `$("#container").find('[data-x]')`

Comment: Are you sure about $("[data-x]")? I'm not getting any match.

Comment: @Dokkat not 100% sure; only if it's defined as an attribute.  Otherwise you can use an ad-hoc `:data` selector, but that may also be slow.  On the other hand, you can probably achieve the same effect using CSS3 animations, which should be much more efficient